# parseInt not getting a added return

Tags: javascript, function, parseint

```
var select;
window.onload = function () {
var select = document.getElementById("money");
console.log(select);
}

function changedepositedInput(objDropDown) {
console.log(parseInt(objDropDown));
var objdeposited = document.getElementById("deposited");
objdeposited.value=parseInt(objdeposited.value);
var total=parseInt(objdeposited.value);
objdeposited.value = parseInt(objDropDown.value+total);
objdeposited.value = parseInt(objdeposited.value);
}
</script>
<h1>Vending Machine Project</h1>
<form name="vendingmachine" action=" ">
Choose Bevrage<br>
        <input name="item" type="radio" value="water" checked="checked">Water 75 cents<br>
        <input name="item" type="radio" value="soda">Soda $1.50<br>
        <input name="item" type="radio" value="coffee">Coffee $1.00<br>
        <input name="item" type="radio" value="beer">Beer $2.00<br>
<p>
    <label>Deposit Money:
        <select name="money" id="money" onchange="changedepositedInput(this)">
            <option>Choose Amount</option>
            <option value="10">10 cents</option>
            <option value="25">25 cents</option>
            <option value="50">50 cents</option>
            <option value="75">75 cents</option>
            <option value="100">$1.00</option>
        </select>
    </label>
</p>
<p>Total Deposited:<input name="deposited" id="deposited" type="text" readonly="TRUE" value=" "></p>
```

using this code I am not getting a return of a solid number, for example in a drop down menu I would select two values ie 50 and 75 and they would combine as 5075, does this mean it is still running it through as string somewhere and if so where?

Comment: You're re-declaring `select`. `var` declares a _local_ variable in the scope.

Comment: what do I need to do to change that, sorry im new to this, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> for example in a drop down menu I would select two values ie 50 and 75 and they would combine as 5075, does this mean it is still running it through as string somewhere and if so where?

Yes, here:

```
objdeposited.value = parseInt(objDropDown.value+total);
```

`objDropDown.value` is a string, e.g. `'50'`, and `total` is a number, e.g. `75`.

In JavaScript, `'50'+75` is `'5075'`.

You can replace these 3 lines

```
var total=parseInt(objdeposited.value);
objdeposited.value = parseInt(objDropDown.value+total);
objdeposited.value = parseInt(objdeposited.value);
```

with

```
var total = parseInt(objdeposited.value);
objdeposited.value = parseInt(objDropDown.value||'0') + total;
```

Edit:

The default value for the `deposited` value was a space `" "` which was causing problems. Change this to the empty string `""`. Also add a `||'0'` to all calls to parseInt (or parseFloat). See http://jsfiddle.net/es2yS/1/ .

Comment: ah, ok is there any way of going about to making this code add up then? or am I leaving something out, I apologize on my lack of knowledge Im new at this, but thank you!

Comment: Yes - just call `parseInt` everytime you use one of the html values. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Its coming up NaN now, would you need to see more of the code to see if I messed something else up? like something in the menu itself?

Comment: @joro4651 Ok that can happen if the `value` is blank. I added a `||'0'` to the above code. If that doesn't fix it, then somehow try to provide example values for the html fields.

Comment: ok I added the rest of the code pertaining to the problem I left out some of the stuff not effecting it, let me know if you see anything, thank you again

Comment: ok that last edit should do it. You may have some logic to work on, but this should fix the errors. If you need help with the math/logic, please start another SO question. Also use jsfiddle when possible - the example provided should be a good start.